# Display "Add to basket" and "Read more" buttons in the products shop page with woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've been playing a little bit with the woocommerce storefront theme and woocommerce, and I wanted to display the "Add to basket" and "Read more" at the same time on the shop page for each product when possible. **I came out with a solution, but I wonder if there is a different way to do this** so I don't have to use CSS to hide a "Read more" button next to another "Read more". Ideally, I wouldn't need CSS and there would be only one "Read more" button when it's not possible to add to the cart.

Here is the code I used:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-buttons-container">';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="button button--read-more">'.__( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' ).'</a>';
        echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
                esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
                isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
                esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
            $product,
            $args
        );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

And some CSS (SCSS) that does the trick:

```
...
      .button {
        margin: 5px 15px;
        & ~ a[href^="http"] {
            display: none;
        }
      }
...
```

Here is how it looks like and hopefully helps to better understand what I want to optimize:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this achieve what you are after? Could be refined more by using the default read more function rather than echoing it.

```
function add_extra_read_more_btn() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_purchasable()) {
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-buttons-container">';
        echo '<a class="button product_type_simple" href="'.get_permalink($product->ID).'">Read more</a>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_extra_read_more_btn', 9 );

function close_extra_read_more_btn_wrap() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_purchasable()) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'close_extra_read_more_btn_wrap', 11 );
```

Comment: This way is better, thanks Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    
    $defaults = array(
        'quantity'   => 1,
        'class'      => implode(
            ' ',
            array_filter(
                array(
                    'button',
                    'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                    $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                    $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                )
            )
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
            'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
            'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
            'rel'              => 'nofollow',
        ),
    );

    $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

    $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-buttons-container">';
        if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="button button--read-more">'.__( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' ).'</a>';
        }
        echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
                esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
                isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
                esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
            $product,
            $args
        );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

This was the key factor:

```
if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="button button--read-more">'.__( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' ).'</a>';
}
```

The $args were missing, so I also added it.

Comment: Product Test 1 has a price and so can be purchased.
Product Test 1 (Copy) has no price and can't be purchased.
Using `is_purchasable()` solves my problem. I hope this helps someone else in the future.